# How to parse through outputted strings of a custom CLI command in bash script?

Tags: bash, parsing

I have a custom CLI command that executes and requires user to enter a password. If the password fails authentication, it will echo some message like "Authentication failed" and I would like to see if the outputted string contains some substring like "fail". However, I noticed that capturing the "output" of a command is not giving me the text it echos on the terminal screen. If I would like to read through all the text the command echoed which doesn't technically come into the "output" bucket, how would I go about doing that?

Example:

```
> custauth
Enter your password: 
Checking if password is correct...
Authentication Failed. Please try again
```

In above example you can see that it doesn't have an "output" but generates text that is displayed to the user. I would like to capture those lines and check for a substring in them rather than its official output

Using `$?` only gives me the exit code but oftentimes the CLI command can fail gracefully and output 0, so I'll need to read through all the statements it echoed.

Comment: did you check both stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 0):

The process can be passed initially by checking the status correctly, which is through

```
#!/bin/bash
# We put here any code that we check for verification 
#like list files to fast exapmle
ls
cpstatus=$?

if [ "$cpstatus" == 0 ]; then
echo "complete"
else
echo "not complete"
fi
wait # Until the upper commands is finish
```

Or if you know what you are achieving, you can check the way out through it, and compare if there is a part of the speech that shows us a specific sentence, for example, if we return a failure, you will add that to the condition
I will attach an example code I wrote to infer the name of the system, for example:

```
System=$(uname -a) #str=$(command)
Substring ='Linux'
if [[ "$System" == *"$Substring"* ]]; then
  echo "Yes is contain $Substring"
fi
```

I hope the solutions helped you, good luck :)